# First movie to show All Persons Fictitious Disclaimer

Tags: production, first-appearance

I was reading [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_persons_fictitious_disclaimer) about **All Persons Fictitious Disclaimer**. The disclaimer came as a result of a case filed by Princess Irina for the 1932 Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer film Rasputin and the Empress.

> The disclaimer came as a result of the 1932 Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer film Rasputin and the Empress, which insinuated that the character Princess Natasha had been raped by Rasputin. Princess Natasha's character was supposedly intended to represent Princess Irina Alexandrovna of Russia, and the real Princess Irina sued MGM for libel. After seeing the film twice, the jury agreed that the princess had been defamed. Princess Irina and her husband Felix Yusupov were reportedly awarded $127,373 in damages by the English Court of Appeal in 1934 and $1 million in an out-of-court settlement with MGM.

However, my question is, **which was the first movie that included this disclaimer?**

Comment: This is one of those "its always been there you never think about it" things, great question.

Comment: @close-voter(s), If a first appearance question is off-topic, then every question with the same tag is off-topic.